# How do I get the current Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android using python?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I made a script python that i want to get the current Latitude and Longitude of the mobile device in android using python, how can i do that, and which module is better ?

Comment: Do you mean that your script should be running on a PC and you want to grab location information from connected android phone?

Comment: My script is about telegram bot and when i run it in my PC i can send message from telegram pc or from telegram in my android,so i want to send message from telegram in android and i get the location my android as form as google map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to retrieve location information from connected android device you could use following script:

```
import sh
from re import findall
#Location[network 11.111111,11.111111 acc=24
LOCATION_PATTERN ="(\w+)\ (\d+.\d+),(\d+.\d+)\ acc"

def set_location_settings(type, on):
    status = "+" if on else "-"
    sh.adb("shell", "settings", "put", "secure", "location_providers_allowed", "{0}{1}".format(status, type))

def get_location_settings():
    return sh.adb("shell", "settings", "get", "secure", "location_providers_allowed")

def is_location_enabled():
    return bool(get_location_settings().strip())

def get_location_data():
    d = dict()
    for (type, lat, long) in findall(LOCATION_PATTERN, str(sh.adb("shell", "dumpsys", "location"))):
        d.setdefault(type, []).append((lat, long))
    return d

if not is_location_enabled():
    set_location_settings("gps", True)
    set_location_settings("network", True)

print get_location_settings()
print get_location_data()
```

It uses `dumpsys` in order to retrieve location information. Also it has option to switch on the `gps`.

The result is a dictionary of type to list of lat,long pairs: 
Example output:

```
{
 'network': [
    ('11.111111', '11.111111'),
    ('11.111111', '11.111111'),
    ('11.111111', '11.111111'),
 ], 
 'gps': [
    ('11.111111', '11.111111'), 
    ('11.111111', '11.111111'),
    ('11.111111', '11.111111')
  ]
 }
```